# Parameter Substitution - Remove the part of the string after the pattern

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a path which looks like the following:

```
/A/B/C/DIRECTORY/D/E/F
```

Now, what I want to achieve using parameter substitution, is cutting of the part of the path after DIRECTORY, no matter where in the path the DIRECTORY is positioned (A, B, C, etc. just stand for random directory names).

After substitution:

```
/A/B/C/DIRECTORY
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# < 1 ]]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 DIRECTORY"
fi

CURRENT_DIRECTORY=$(pwd)
DIRECTORY=$1

cd ${CURRENT_DIRECTORY%!(DIRECTORY)/*}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. I could implement this using awk or sed but I'm interested if it is possible using only parameter substitution.

Answer (score 2):

May be this can help -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] D="A/B/C/DIRECTORY/D/E/F"

[jaypal:~/Temp] echo $D
A/B/C/DIRECTORY/D/E/F

[jaypal:~/Temp] c=${D%/*/*/*}

[jaypal:~/Temp] echo $c
A/B/C/DIRECTORY
```

Answer (score 1):

Try next solution:

```
cd ${CURRENT_DIRECTORY/${DIRECTORY}*/""}
```

EDIT:

More accurate answer would be appending your directory after removing last part:

```
cd ${CURRENT_DIRECTORY/${DIRECTORY}*/""}$DIRECTORY
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ D="/A/B/C/foo/D/E"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo "${D/foo*/}"
/A/B/C/
```

of course, this isn't perfect:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ D="/A/B/C/foobar/D/foo/E"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo "${D/foo*/}"
/A/B/C/
```

Read the bash man page and search for "**Pattern substitution**".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Birei, I came to this (not perfect but good enough solution:

```
#/bin/bash

if [[ $# < 1 ]]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 BASENAME"
fi

echo ${PWD/%$1*/$1}
```

Example:

```
$ PWD=/home/ltorvalds/workspace
$ ./up.sh ltorvalds
/home/ltorvalds
```